# How to easily update an order with Paypal before capturing the transaction?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, paypal, titanium

I'm developing a game on iPhone with Appcelerator Titanium (wrapper in javascript) and I want to sell virtual goods with Paypal (Titanium has a module for that).

The thing is I don't want to be charged the whole transaction fee right away: I want the user to be able to add some extra stuff to the order a few minutes later. In other words, I want to authorize a first payment, then offer an update if necessary, then later capture the transaction (close it).

Does Paypal offer this kind of thing? I don't see it with Ti.Paypal (the titanium module).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. Paypal doesn't offer such a thing. If you want to do this, keep it local until you know the user is done, and then send it to PayPal. Not the other way around!

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Apple will reject the application anyway. You in app purchase of virtual goods must go through apple, not PayPal

Comment: Wow. Ok. Thank you for telling me that. So if there are physical goods, it's okay?